# Why are neural networks equivalent to kernel methods?

Tags: neural-network, kernel

I read a recent paper by Pedro Domingos, claiming that [Every Model Learned by Gradient Descent Is Approximately a Kernel Machine](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.00152).

I wanted to understand the key idea a little better. Why are neural networks equivalent to kernel methods? And in particular, is there any method to actually derive the equivalent kernel from an existing neural network?

Comment: some specific classes of neural networks are equivalent to kernel-based methods with the difference that NNs learn their own kernels. This blog post [A Statistical View of Deep Learning (III): Memory and Kernels](http://blog.shakirm.com/2015/04/a-statistical-view-of-deep-learning-iii-memory-and-kernels/) can shed some lights.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the paper only implies that under certain conditions, neural networks and kernel functions exhibit an equivalence.

This is because the [neural networks](https://databasecamp.de/en/ml/artificial-neural-networks) with their hidden layers converge during the training process to some optimal weight values for each [neuron](https://databasecamp.de/en/ml/perceptrons). These values align with a kernel matrix which means that their representations can be approximated by a kernel function.

Take for example [support vector machines (SVMs)](https://databasecamp.de/en/ml/svm-explained) where the boundary between classes is determined by the similarity/kernel function between the inputs. A [neural network](https://databasecamp.de/en/ml/artificial-neural-networks) would learn this through complex non-linear transformations using their [activation function](https://databasecamp.de/en/ml/softmax-function).